# Twitter Logging and Scala Custom Handlers

Tags: scala, logging, twitter

I'm using [Twitter's logging framework](https://github.com/twitter/util/tree/master/util-logging) in Scala, version 6.5.0.

I've written a toy usage example:

```
import com.twitter.logging._

object TestFormatter extends Formatter 
{
    override def format( record : java.util.logging.LogRecord) = "TEST %s> ".format( record.getLevel.getName ) + formatText(record) + lineTerminator
}

object Main extends App
{
    override def main( args : Array[String] ) : Unit =
    {
        // obtain a logger
        val log = Logger.get( getClass )
        // clear any existing message handlers
        Logger.clearHandlers
        // add a new handler, using my toy formatter
        log.addHandler( ConsoleHandler( TestFormatter, Some( Level.DEBUG ) )() )
        // log a couple of test messages
        log.debug( "DEBUG LOG" )
        log.warning( "WARNING LOG" )
    }
}
```

The class TestFormatter isn't really necessary, but will help to highlight my problem. I'm pretty sure that what I should see from this by way of output from this code is something along the lines of:

```
TEST DEBUG> DEBUG LOG
TEST WARNING> WARNING LOG
```

However, what I actually get is:

```
TEST WARNING> WARNING LOG
WARNING: WARNING LOG
```

This raises two issues:

1. Why has some other handler also handled my warning message, despite me clearing existing handlers? - SOLVED
2. Why, when I've set the level of my logger to debug, has the message I logged at debug level not been handled?

If anyone could throw any light on either of these problems, I'd be most grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, I wasn't using the framework in the expected manner. I've found that the [LoggerFactory](https://github.com/twitter/util/blob/master/util-logging/src/main/scala/com/twitter/logging/LoggerFactory.scala) class is the way that you're supposed to make changes to your loggers. My main method should have been as follows:

```
override def main( args : Array[String] ) : Unit =
{
    val log = Logger.get( "" )

    LoggerFactory(
        node = "",
        level = Some( Level.DEBUG ),
        handlers = List( ConsoleHandler( TestFormatter, Some( Level.DEBUG ) ) )
    ).apply()

    log.debug( "DEBUG LOG" )
    log.warning( "WARNING LOG" )
}
```

I'm still not entirely sure why the original code doesn't work, especially since the source of LoggerFactory seems to suggest that it registers the new Handlers by calling addHandler().

However, the output of this main method is:

```
TEST DEBUG> DEBUG LOG
TEST WARNING> WARNING LOG
```

which is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, you can change your code to use `Logger.clearHandlers` to get rid of the additional handler.

Second question: you could add `log.setLevel(Level.DEBUG)` to get the output you are expecting. As for what setting the level of the handler does, it doesn't seem to control anything. So it is bug; at the very least a documentation bug in their library.